# Why won't my my catch block work?

Tags: java, oop, io

I'm trying to test out the `throws FileNotFoundException`.  At first, I placed my `exec.txt` in my project folder to test out my `"testing"` string & it works fine when I run my program.

But now, I removed my `exec.txt` file from my folder to see if the `catch()` part in the `main` method would work, but it doesn't.  The `File not found` part of the `catch()` part won't appear in the console.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Crashable {

public static void openFile(String f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter f1 = new PrintWriter(f);
    f1.write("testing");
    f1.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String f = "exec.txt";

    try {
        openFile(f);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Re-read the docs for the PrintWriter constructor: "If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created." The exception is only thrown if it can't create the file.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, an `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown when a file couldn't be accessed or created.

> FileNotFoundException - If the given string does not denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or creating the file

In your case it could create a new file, so no exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it to throw the execption by trying creating the file in a non-existing dir:

```
   String f = "zzz/exec.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You never throw the exception in the `openFile` method. From the Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File)),

> public PrintWriter(File file)
>                   throws FileNotFoundException
>
> Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, with the specified file. This convenience constructor creates the necessary
>   intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will encode characters using
>   the default charset for this instance of the Java virtual machine.
>
> Parameters:
>       file - The file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new
>   file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is
>   buffered.

So if the file isn't there, you create a new file. So essentially, everything is working because although the file isn't there, when you create the `PrintWriter` object, it creates a new file, and doesn't throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating a new file every time with this piece of code :

`PrintWriter f1 = new PrintWriter(f);
f1.write("testing");
f1.close();`

Instead try this :

```
public static void openFile(String f) throws FileNotFoundException {
File file = new File(f);
if(!file.exists())
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
else
{
    //do Something with the file
}}
```

Hope it helps..